# C program Do while doesnt work

Tags: c, do-while

A have a problem with my program. I dont know what im doing wrong but loop do while doesnt work. At and program should ask "If you want to run this program again, press T.Other key should close this program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
int f;
int g;
int h;
int d = 0;
char e;
srand(time(0));
do {

    printf("How many numbers do you want to show: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &a);
    printf("od: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &b);
    printf("do: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &c);

    h = c + 1;
    f = b - h; 
    for (d; d < a; d++) {
        printf("%i ", b + rand() % f);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Restart program? T- Yes");
    scanf_s("%s", &e);

} while (e == 't');

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Program works fine, but when i press T at the end. it will close. Im using Visual Studio 2015

Now my code is below:

```
do {

    printf("How many numbers do u want: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &a);
    printf("od: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &b);
    printf("do: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &c);

    h = c + 1; 
    f = b - h; 
    //printf("%i %i %i\n", h, f);
    for (d; d < a; d++) {
        printf("%i ", b + rand() % f);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Restart? T- yes");
    scanf_s("%c", &e);
} while (e == 't' || e == 'T');
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

But it still doesnt work. I cant enter any letter. When i press any key a windows is going to close

Comment: `while(e=='t')`->`while(e=='t' || e=='T')`, `scanf_s("%s", &e);`->`scanf_s("%c", &e);`

Comment: `%s` is for a string. `%c` is for char.

Comment: Unrelated, but why does the user need to press `T` instead of `Y` (for __Y__ es)?

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", &e);` --> `scanf_s(" %c", &e, 1);`, `e == 't'` --> `e == 'T'`

Comment: I have now  while(e=='t' || e=='T') and  scanf_s("%c", &e); but it still doesnt work

Comment: @Finer Try my comment.

Comment: `scanf_s` needs an additional length argument passed for format types `%c` and `%s` and `%[]`. Please take note of compiler warnings: *'scanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string*.

Comment: `for (d; d < a; d++)` what will the initial value of `d` be on the *second* iteration of the `do` loop?

Comment: Re the question edit: you have not put the space in front of `%c` and still have not given a length argument in `scanf_s("%c", &e);` **Do not ignore the compiler warnings**. Also, that instruction will leave a newline in the input buffer, which will be read by `_getch()`. Please read all the answers and all the comments carefully.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed, this is because you're trying to get a `"%s"` and, therefore, you can't compare it to a character. Use `"%c"` instead, or use `strcmp` function to compare 2 char arrays.

By the way, be aware that scanf_s is a Microsoft only function. Not sure if visual studio is forcing you to use it, but the common usage of scanf wouldn't hurt, check it out:

```
scanf("%c", &e);
```

Comment: As this follows `scanf_s("%i", &c);` it will read a newline, unless you add a space before the `%c`, making it `scanf(" %c", &e);`

Comment: A typo in the above comment where I used `scanf` instead of `scanf_s` but which would actually be right, because the length argument required by `scanf_s` (but not by `scanf`) is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Do you press 'T'? because 'T' and 't' are not the same character. check [the ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)
Your program will continue while you press a 't' so with a 'T' or anything else it will stop.
ps: You may want to use "read(0, &e, 1);" or "scanf_s("%c", &e);" instead of "scanf_s("%s", &e);" (last line of do while), because you have a char and if you enter a string like "Mr T. says yes" it will overwrite your memory which is never good.
As a reminder char is 1 byte in memory, with '&' you can access its place in memory, so it acts like a string but if you write more than 1 character it will just write in the following memory which isn't attributted to your program. it will probably do nothing but it can overwrite another of your variable or worse overwrite another program in your computer (hopefully not something important like a window's program or else!)

[char and string basics](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-tutorials-difference-between-character-string/)